# 'xaa' would overwrite input: error in using split command in bash

Tags: bash, split

I am trying to split a 13Gb file into equal chunks using Linux Bash Shell in windows 10 by:

```
split -n l/13 myfile.csv
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
split: 'xaa' would overwrite input; aborting
```

the xaa which is created is empty.

I have also tried using:

```
split -l 9000000 myfile.csv
```

which wields the same results.

I have used the split command before with similar arguments with no problem.

Any ideas what am I missing?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: even if i provide my own prefix I still get the same error:

```
split -n l/13 myfile.csv completenewprefix
split: 'completenewprefixaa' would overwrite input; aborting
```

EDIT2:

```
ls -di completenewprefixaa myfile.csv
1 completenewprefixaa  1 myfile.csv

findmnt -T .
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/u U:     drvfs  rw,relatime,case=off
```

Comment: `the xaa which is created is empty` so remove the file. Empty means it exists.

Comment: the xaa is created as part of the split. it doesn't exist before that

Comment: The [error comes only](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/split.c#L470) if the input file is the same as output. Check for symlinks, etc. Is `myfile.csv` on another partition? A bit paranoid, check `ls -di myfile.csv xaa`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: That's still valid. Looks like a bug has been filed on it - https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2012-06/msg00066.html

Comment: I tried to provide 'completelyuniqueprefix' as a prefix, with the same results

Comment: @Inian Yes, the error/check is valid. But somehow the error `would overwrite input; aborting` triggers for @vagraf, so somehow inode of `xaa` and `myfile.csv` have to be the same (how?). @vagraf what version of split do you have?

Comment: @KamilCuk split (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Comment: What would `ls -di myfile.csv xaa completenewprefixxaa` output? Is the directory mounted somehow specially? What would `findmnt -T .` output?

Comment: @KamilCuk please check EDIT2

Comment: So the inode number is the same - they are the same file. I guess this is most probably the fault of that `drvfs` filesystem.

Comment: thanks for the info, I will look into that